# Spring boot return 'HTTP/1.1 200' not 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

Client expecting the "`OK`" after "`200`" when receiving HTTP response as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Without the "`OK`", the client can NOT parse the HTTP response correctly. How to fix the problem

---

I had fix it

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory)container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer)connector -> {
                ProtocolHandler protocolHandler = connector.getProtocolHandler();
                if (protocolHandler != null && protocolHandler instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
                    AbstractProtocol protocol = (AbstractProtocol)protocolHandler;
                    // fix tomcat 8.5 can't send reason phrase
                    protocol.setSendReasonPhrase(true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You can find required substring from the returned response.

Comment: I don't know how to do

Comment: Use a better client?

Comment: no, I need to return with ok

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Run `curl -D - <your URL>` and check the output. I get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` in a Spring Boot (version `1.4.2.RELEASE`) app.

Answer (score 5):

See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

> sendReasonPhrase
>
> Set this attribute to true if you wish to have a reason phrase in the response. The default value is false.
>
> **Note**: This option is deprecated and will be removed in Tomcat 9. The reason phrase will not be sent.

Discussion: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60362

I would definitely try fixing/changing the client.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP specification ([RFC 2616 Section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1)) says<sup>1</sup> that the "reason phrase" consists of zero or more characters.  It also says:

> The reason phrases listed here are only
> recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without
> affecting the protocol.

In other words, the HTTP specifications allow a server to use different text for the reason phrases, or leave it out entirely.

The latest version of the HTTP specification ([RFC 7230 Section 3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)) is more explicit about client behavior.

> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a
> textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly
> out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were
> more frequently used with interactive text clients.  **A client SHOULD
> ignore the reason-phrase content.**

If your client relies on a specific value for the reason phrase of any response, it is non-interoperable, and arguably broken.

In this case, you have encountered a case where the developers of Tomcat have decided to leave out the reason phrases .... presumably because they are redundant.  While you can work around this behavior in Tomcat 8.5 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610913/139985)), with Tomcat 9 onwards you will have no option other than fixing your (broken!) client code to not depend on the reason phrase.

In short: if you plan to continue using Tomcat servers in the future, you should fix or replace the client.

---

<sup>1 - The wording in RFC 7231 is virtually identical.</sup>